# How to change the default password in Solr?

Tags: ubuntu, security, search, solr

I have a Solr server with Ubuntu 20.04

I followed the doumentation, but I cannot change the default password.

How can I do this ?

```
ubuntu@www-example-com ~ $ $ curl --user solr:SolrRocks http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/authentication -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{"set-user": {"solr":"hhjhjhj765"}}'
$: command not found
```

**UPDATE**

```
ubuntu@www-example-com ~ $ curl --user solr:SolrRocks http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/authentication -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{"set-user": {"solr":"hhjhjhj765"}}'


{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":500,
    "QTime":4},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException"],
    "msg":"Failed persisting security.json to /var/solr/data/security.json",
    "trace":"org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Failed persisting security.json to /var/solr/data/security.json\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.SecurityConfHandlerLocal.persistConf(SecurityConfHandlerLocal.java:89)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.SecurityConfHandler.doEdit(SecurityConfHandler.java:134)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.SecurityConfHandler.handleRequestBody(SecurityConfHandler.java:85)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:199)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdmin(HttpSolrCall.java:820)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:786)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:546)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:423)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:350)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1711)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1347)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1678)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1249)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:152)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:781)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:917)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\nCaused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /var/solr/data/security.json\n\tat sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)\n\tat sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)\n\tat sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)\n\tat sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)\n\tat java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:434)\n\tat java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:216)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.SecurityConfHandlerLocal.persistConf(SecurityConfHandlerLocal.java:84)\n\t... 42 more\n",
    "code":500}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have copied a `$` from the example:

```
ubuntu@www-example-com ~ $ $ curl --user solr:SolrRocks http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/authentication -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{"set-user": {"solr":"hhjhjhj765"}}'
```

Use:

```
curl --user solr:SolrRocks http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/authentication -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{"set-user": {"solr":"hhjhjhj765"}}'
```

`$` is often used in example commands to indicate that the command can be used with an unprivileged user. `$: command not found` means that the system failed to find the command `$`.

The permissions for `/var/solr/data/security.json` are wrong. Grant the user running the `solr` process read write access to that file.

Comment: Thank you, indeed I was wrong. But I still have an error. I updated the question.

Comment: `sudo chown -R solr:solr /var/solr/data/security.json` Thank you. Should we do this? And do I have to change the owner after changing the password or can I leave it solr?

Comment: yes. that looks right. no need to change that. the solr process just needs access to that file